# "in any situation" vs "in any situations"

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing an affirmation to motivate myself to be more assertive.

Choice 1:
"I am assertive in any situation."

Choice 2:
"I am assertive in any situations."

The question is:
Should I use the word situation in singular or plural form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical. In my opinion the first is better for your purposes, however. The use of *any* with the plural ***situations***, summons to mind just general situations that might occur. ***Any situation*** on the other hand, implies consideration of more extreme cases. It more strongly conveys *all* potential situations.

Having said this, both options are open to you, so if you want to be more assertive, why don't you choose the one that you like the best!

Comment: How would you answer "How do you pronounce X" if not by enunciating the word requested? How can that be a Complement?  I could never talk about the tongue brushing against the alveolar ridge or dental fricative palava :) Anyway, thank you for replying, I actually found your comment to be more useful than your posted answer. You could undelete and add those thoughts.

Comment: Your comments were referring to a completely separate [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324568/how-do-you-call-vs-what-do-you-call) I had asked. To an outsider they wouldn't make much sense, so they ought to be deleted. :)

Answer (score 2):

[**Any**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Any), adjective:

> - You use any in front of a singular countable noun to talk about each thing or person of a particular type. *Look it up in any large dictionary.
>     These are things that any man might do under pressure.*
> - You use any in front of a plural countable noun to talk about all things or people of a particular type.
>     *The patients know their rights like any other consumers.
>     You use any in front of an uncountable noun to talk about an amount of something.
>     Throw any leftovers in the bin.*
> - When you use any in front of a singular countable noun or an uncountable noun, you use a singular form of a verb with it.
>     *Any book that attracts children as much as this has to be taken seriously.
>     While any poverty remains, it must have the first priority.*
> - When you use any in front of a plural countable noun, you use a plural form of a verb with it.
>     *Before any decisions are made, ministers are carrying out a full enquiry.*
>
> <sub>*Collins COBUILD English Usage*</sub>

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+any+situation%2Cin+any+situations&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cin%20any%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20any%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20any%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cin%20any%20situations%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20any%20situations%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIn%20any%20situations%3B%2Cc0) shows a far more common use of the singular form in this case.

Comment: Before I asked this question I had searched for answers from dictionaries and web sites. I can find rules about how to use "any" with singular; plural; countable and uncountable noun. I've found those rules lead to the same answer: Both are grammatical. These rules are not useful since in my case I am trying to choose one for an affirmation, it has something to do with "to make firm". I think Araucaria's answer is useful in that it has differentiate

Comment: I am pleased you have found the answer you were looking for!