# How do you call components that make up a car's engine?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for the common way to call components like oil filter or fuel pump. I thought about car parts or auto parts but I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: [Engine parts](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/engine2.htm)

Comment: BTW, it's "What do you call ...", not "How do you call ..."

Comment: @HotLicks you should've posted this link [How do you call..? vs. What do you call…?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324568/how-do-you-call-vs-what-do-you-call) :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Auto parts" is the usual term in the US for parts anywhere on an automobile, but this includes parts of the body, wheels, transmission, etc.  **Engine parts** would refer more unambiguously to parts of the engine, and the term is a perfectly normal usage that is readily understood.

Note, however, that if you want to refer to a set of parts that does not include, eg, the water pump, but rather only parts inside the engine then you would need a qualifier such as "internal engine parts".  And if, on the other hand, you want to include, say, the radiator you would have choose another term as well, as a piece such as the radiator may or or may not be regarded as an engine part.

Comment: Says who? (Of course, "engine parts" it is.)

Comment: An appropriate term for the parts attached to the engine would be ancillaries (see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ancillary Noun 1.1)

Comment: @SimonB - Which will get you dumb looks in the auto parts store.

Answer (score 0):

"Components" is fine, if you're talking about the pieces -- such as the water pump, injectors, valves, and so on -- that make up the larger system.

Such things can generally be purchased at an "auto parts store" or an "auto parts dealer."