# What do you call a negatively connoted advice-giver?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people (especially the older ones) are very prone to give other people moral advice. And I search for how to call somebody who is doing this so extensively that his environment is just exhausted (sick of it) from hearing that much advices.

Example: If a group of boys would try to return their ball of a neighbor by themselves, he would point out that it's not a good decision and they should rather ask the neighbor.
If a group of students have to do the homework together and someone has the solution for it, he would point out, that this is morally not alright and they should do it by themselves.

Comment: Is that a nay-sayer or scold?

Comment: Could be a [busybody](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busybody).  Can you add an example of what the person would do or say, and how you would use the desired word?

Comment: @Hellion nailed it, as usual. That word or any synonyms you can find for it in a thesaurus.

Comment: "warning" or a ... if you want to try to make a noun out of it "warner" (not really common). If you wanted to get even more neutral(perhaps too much so ) you could call them a 'counselor', who's duty is in a large part keeping people in order (even if there is also positive advice mixed in).  Certainly when you "run something by an attorney" you are often looking for where a business agreement might go wrong or astray from your intent.

Comment: It's  'give advice', not 'advices' (even when speaking of many different occasions).

Comment: It's rather amusing that 'busybody' is offered in a previous thread for '[someone who] doesn't respect personal space'.

Comment: In English, we normally ask: [What do you call...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324568/how-do-you-call-vs-what-do-you-call)? Please edit your post, and spread the word :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ***busybody*** fits your requirement.  The basic definitions are somewhat tame:

> a person who meddles in the affairs of others
> <sub>*from Merriam Webster's [Word Central](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?book=Student&va=busybody)*</sub>
>
> a person who is too interested in the private lives of other people
> <sub>*from Merriam Webster's [Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/busybody)*</sub>

But this explanation from [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/busybody) makes it clear that the word really suits your situation:

> A busybody is a nosy, meddling person, who's very interested in what other people say and do. If you're a busybody, you can't help offering advice to friends, whether they want it or not.
>
> Busybodies are known for trying to help with situations in which they're not necessarily welcome or needed. You could describe your mom as a busybody if she asks prying questions and tries to orchestrate your romantic life. The word busybody comes from a now-obsolete meaning of busy, "prying" or "meddlesome."

Comment: Though not literally the same thing, 'buttinsky' is often used similarly to 'busybody'.

Comment: @Mitch that's another good word, you should post that as an answer.